# $ionicLoading, template não funciona

Tags: ionic

Quando chamo a função `show()` passando o atributo `content: '...'` o texto do loading é alterado, conforme abaixo.

```
$rootScope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading...'
});
```

Porém quando uso template, conforme abaixo, não funciona.

```
$rootScope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
    template: 'Loading...'
});
```

Porque ? qual a diferença entre eles ? na [documentação do ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/) nem possui menção ao `content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das possíveis causas para este problema é a versão do `Ionic` e ou das bibliotecas que você está utilizando.

[Aqui](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoeXrx) tem um exemplo que mostra o funcionamento do *loading* customizado corretamente.

Se o seu app for local(offline) é só fazer o [Download](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-bower) da biblioteca `ionic.bundle.js` e suas dependências, e adicionar manualmente ao projeto.

Caso seja um aplicativo online voce pode utilizar a CDN do `Ionic`.

```
 <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

O `ionic.bundle.js` é um conjunto de todas as bibliotecas tanto `ionic` e `angular` para o funcionamento do mesmo.